# ERROR: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432 docker migrate

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to migrate the data but it always cant find my postgreSQL.

```
version: '3'
services:
  server:
    build: ./server
    ports:
      - 3002:3002
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      CORS_ALLOW_ORIGINS: http://localhost:8080,http://localhost:80
      PORT: 3002
      DEBUG: vuichoi*
      DEBUG_HIDE_DATE: 1
      SECRET_OR_PRIVATE_KEY: secret
      SECRET_OR_PUBLIC_KEY: secret
      DATABASE_URL: postgres://vuichoi:@db:5432/vuichoi #point the server container to the db container's IP address
      command: bash -c "sequelize db:migrate && sequelize db:seed:all"
  db:
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: vuichoi
      POSTGRES_DB: vuichoi
    image: postgres:10
```

config.json

```
{
"development": {
    "username": "vuichoi",
    "database": "vuichoi",
    "host": "localhost",
    "dialect": "postgres"
},
"test": {
    "username": "vuichoi",
    "password": "vuichoi",
    "database": "database_test",
    "host": "localhost",
    "dialect": "postgres"
},
"production": {
    "use_env_variable": "DATABASE_URL"
}
```

}

after docker-compose up --build 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zaspn.png)

when im trying to migrate:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5V0LU.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you running the server and the database at same time, and when the server starts it tries to connect to the DB that is still being started/created.

A solution for this problem is using a script that only launches the server a few seconds after the db has started. In 
https://github.com/PedroS11/node-postgres-redis-docker you have an example, the entry-point.sh. Or, if you want, search  for "wait for it docker", and you will find a script for this and with more examples.

Comment: I saw that entry-point.sh
Then can you help me how to run the script from that file while the docker is running. 
Thanks for your help

Comment: I told you something wrong, in my repo, I have a wait-for-it.sh file inside api, copy it and paste on your server folder than in your docker-compose.yml replace the command in the server for something like this
    command: ["./wait-for-it.sh", "db:5432", "--", "npm", "run", "db"]. And create a npm command on your package.json "db": "sequelize db:migrate && sequelize db:seed:all"

Comment: Okay. I got it. Thank you. :D XD

Answer (score 7):

i fixed by replace "localhost" in config.json by "host.docker.internal" then it works smoothly. the problem maybe it cannot find my Db container

Comment: Did you configer it in windows OS?

Answer (score 2):

You should give names to your containers in docker-compose file like that:

```
db:
  container_name: my_database
  ports:
    - 5432:5432
  environment:
    POSTGRES_USER: vuichoi
    POSTGRES_DB: vuichoi
  image: postgres:10
server:
  container_name: my_server
```

And change host's in your config.json

```
{
  "development": {
  "username": "vuichoi",
  "database": "vuichoi",
  "host": "my_database",
  "dialect": "postgres"
},
```

Besides, your database can start after you migration scripts ran.
For fix this problem you can add

```
server:
  container_name: my_server
  restart: always
```

So, your server will restart after first unsuccessful attempt & migration script will work correctly